# tidyr: spread without expanding all columns

Tags: r, tidyr

Getting around to learning `tidyr` and having trouble with `spread()`.

Here's a fake experimental dataset:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- structure(list(mood = c(0.855, -0.103, 0.421, -0.222, 0.772, -0.027, -1.088, 0.923, -1.516, -1.503, -0.358, -0.357, -0.344, 0.294, 0.348, -0.174, 0.872, -1.188, 0.842, -0.246, -0.758, 0.674, 0.045, 0.72, -1.253, 0.00599999999999995, -0.0749999999999999,1.623, -1.754, -0.44, -0.607, -0.083, -0.827, -0.337, -0.6, 0.429, -0.383, -1.755, 0.894, 0.146, -0.658, -0.409, -0.531, 1.388, -0.688, 0.521, -0.662, 0.852, -1.363, 0.18, -0.775, 0.393, -0.926, 0.809, -0.857, 0.889, 0.0969999999999999, -1.553, -0.21,1.769, -0.114, -0.203, 0.805, 0.186, 0.286, -0.076, 0.137, 1.208, 0.33, 0.34, 0.832, 0.815, -0.427, 0.444, -0.838, 1.45, 1.701, -2.265, 0.531, 0.808),
  subj = structure(c(1L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,11L, 13L, 1L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 1L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 1L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L), .Label = c("s1", "s10", "s11", "s12", "s13", "s14", "s15", "s16", "s17", "s18", "s19", "s2", "s20", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9"), class = "factor"),
  depressed = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
  activity = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("exercize", "relaxation"), class = "factor"), 
  drug = structure(c(1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("placebo", "SSRI"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("mood", "subj", "depressed", "activity", "drug"), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = "data.frame")
```

Taking a peek at `df`, we can see that `activity` and `drug` are within-subjects factors whereas `depressed` is a between-subjects factor:

```
head(arrange(df, subj))
    mood subj depressed   activity    drug
1  0.855   s1       yes relaxation placebo
2 -0.758   s1       yes relaxation    SSRI
3 -0.658   s1       yes   exercize placebo
4 -0.114   s1       yes   exercize    SSRI
5 -1.503  s10        no relaxation placebo
6 -0.440  s10        no relaxation    SSRI
```

I'd like to convert `df` to wide form where each subject's `mood` is represented in a separate column and each row corresponds to the combinations of `activity` and `drug`. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to avoid creating sets of rows for each level of `depressed`. Here's what I have so far:

```
df %>% spread(subj, mood) %>% `[`(1:5)
  depressed   activity    drug     s1   s10
1        no   exercize placebo     NA  0.18
2        no   exercize    SSRI     NA  0.34
3        no relaxation placebo     NA -1.50
4        no relaxation    SSRI     NA -0.44
5       yes   exercize placebo -0.658    NA
6       yes   exercize    SSRI -0.114    NA
7       yes relaxation placebo  0.855    NA
8       yes relaxation    SSRI -0.758    NA
```

I would like to avoid expanding `depressed` so the resulting output would only have four rows.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want four columns, but you're spreading the subject column which has 20 levels, so you're going to get 20 columns of subject moods plus the other columns. Can you show your desired output for just the first or first two subjects?

Comment: I'm confused too.  4 columns; what are their names?  How many rows do you expect?  Do you want to do any aggregation?

Comment: Perhaps something like `df %>% select(-depressed) %>% spread(subj, mood) %>% select(1:4)` is what you want?

Comment: @docendodiscimus, I made several guesses but in the end couldn't think of anything sensible.  I think we need to wait for clarification.

Comment: @BenBolker, you are right.

Comment: Sorry everybody that was a typo--four rows.  So each row would correspond to the four observations per subject. Thanks.

Comment: But yes @docendo_discimus the snippet you provided is exactly what I was looking for. Post it as an answer and I will accept gladly

Comment: ribo, please feel free to answer your question yourself and accept the solution. I was just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @decendodiscimus for contributing a solution in the comments.

Eliminating between subject factors in a "wide" format is a simple matter of using `dplyr::select` and `-`.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- tbl_df(df)
> df %>% select(-depressed) %>% spread(subj, mood)
Source: local data frame [4 x 22]

    activity    drug     s1    s10    s11    s12    s13    s14    s15    s16
1   exercize placebo -0.658  0.180 -0.775  0.393 -0.926  0.809 -0.857  0.889
2   exercize    SSRI -0.114  0.340  0.832  0.815 -0.427  0.444 -0.838  1.450
3 relaxation placebo  0.855 -1.503 -0.358 -0.357 -0.344  0.294  0.348 -0.174
4 relaxation    SSRI -0.758 -0.440 -0.607 -0.083 -0.827 -0.337 -0.600  0.429
```